# Streaming .mp4 file while it is making from another program

Tags: android, video, streaming, gstreamer

I'm looking for information to make a remote control service on Android platform

so, I just noticed that there is a shell command called "screen record" in Android 4.4 so

I'm curious about that it is possible to make stream from a device which is making .mp4 file through screen record to another device. if so, can i modify the screen record to be a program can deliver video stream directly?

I might use Gstreamer if it is possible..

Sorry for poor writing but i really need your opinions

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to send frames over RTP but it you need sound too, it's going to be a pain to implement. I recall VLC mediaplayer has some functionality similar to this, maybe they have a nice library for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did something like this with recording video output of MediaRecorder to remote device. Here is a sample code...

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_LQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QCIF);
recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_LQ);

Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.43.242", 42590);    // IP Address and Port Number of remote device
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());

recorder.setPreviewDisplay(sh.getSurface());
recorder.prepare();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        recorder.start();
    }
}, 2000);
```

May be, you could use the same procedure with your code !

Good Luck. :)